# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'store.products'?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I recently started learning Django. Faced an error. I have created a new application and I am trying to import it into the main project, but I am getting an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs8Rw.png)

I tried doing it like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epbVs.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a wrong project structure, but here is a solution.

Add those lines to your settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
)
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
```

After that, just use `from products.views import index`.
If it doesn't work, just print `BASE_DIR`, and play with number of `os.path.dirname` functions, `BASE_DIR` must be the absolute path to your `/absole/to/TestProject/store` folder.